# How to increment Yposition value for maincamera in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a scenario in which i want to increase y position value for main-camera in unity but it is not like script attached to main-camera something like to increment y position value for main-camera by script attached from another game-object.Could someone help me on this regard.

For increment Y position value with script attached to Main-camera object i guess to write code like this:
Debug.Log(transform.position.y);
transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 4, Space.World);

But i supposed to increment y position value for main-camera by script attached from another game-object.

Comment: You can access the camera tagged with Main Camera with `Camera.main.transform.position`, so you'll write something like `Camera.main.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 4, Space.World);`

Answer (score 0):

Attach the following script to the desired game object, then, select the gameobject you have attached the script and drag & drop the Camera gameobject into the `Target` field

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag & Drop the camera you want to move
    public Transform Target ;

    // Specify the movement you want to apply
    public Vector3 movement = new Vector3( 0, 4, 0 ) ;

    private void Start()
    {
         // Automatically retrieve the Camera tagged "MainCamera" if no target specified
         if( Target == null )
             Target = Camera.main.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

         if( Target == null )
            Debug.LogError("No target specified !");
         else
             Target.Translate( movement * Time.deltaTime, Space.World ) ;
    }    
}
```